# Ampersands are escaped when Redirecting in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want the Apache Server to redirect the URL `https://frot.io/cv` to `https://latexonline.cc/compile?git=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffrot-io%2Fcurriculum-vitae&target=main.tex&command=xelatex` and thus inserted a *Redirect* statement in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

# Redirect to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect frot.io/cv
Redirect 301 "/cv" "https://latexonline.cc/compile?git=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffrot-io%2Fcurriculum-vitae&target=main.tex&command=xelatex"
```

However, this redirects to `https://latexonline.cc/compile?git=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffrot-io%2Fcurriculum-vitae%26target%3Dmain.tex%26command%3Dxelatex` (the two ampersands and equal signs are escaped) which leads to an error.

**How can I prevent apache to escape ampersands in the URL?**

I tried to escape those as well (`%26` and `%3D`) but am as well wrongly redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved with help from the support:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /cv https://latexonline.cc/pending?git=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffrot-io%2Fcurriculum-vitae&target=main.tex&command=xelatex
RewriteBase /
...
```